# "I can see this being useful." Why not “be”?

Tags: verbs, present-participles, verbs-of-perception

I assume this is a correct sentence. I don't think "*I can see this be useful" works, though. Why is that? I thought verbs of perception worked with both the infinitive and the continuous (-ing form): “I see him play” / “I see him playing”.

Comment: Not the best form, but you could write ""I can see this *to be* useful."

Answer (score 2):

That's a different meaning of *see*. When *see* means visual perception, either mood can be used:

- “I see him play”: with the infinitive, I see the action as a whole.
- “I see him playing”: with the present participle, I see the action in progress.

But when *see* means “imagine” or “anticipate”, as in your first example, it's always constructed with a participle, without any implication that the action is imagined to be in progress.

> I can see this being useful.
>   I can't see her ​accepting the ​job in the ​present ​circumstances.   ([Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see))
>   I can’t see him earning any more anywhere else.   ([Oxford Dictionary of British & World English](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/see))

Comment: I don't think you've really addressed the point OP is asking about. Your example *I see him playing = I see the action in progress* isn't at all the same as, say, *I see him playing **for England when he grows up***, which *does* match OP's cited usage. That version is about something you *can imagine might happen in the future*, and it would be difficult to defend the idea that there's any meaningful allusion to *continuously playing for England*, as opposed to simply *making the squad* (effectively, a one-time event with no real "duration").

Comment: @FumbleFingers “I see him playing for England …” is another example of the second meaning. I don't understand your point: I never claim that there's any allusion to duration in the second meaning.

Comment: I guess you're right. I was really addressing the fact that your *first* section isn't what OP is actually asking about, but reading the question more carefully I see it *is* relevant, because he's conflating a rule applicable to *see = actual act of visual perception* with the metaphoric usage where it actually means *anticipate*.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the explanation on the Cambridge Dictionaries website: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/hear-see-etc-object-infinitive-or-ing